# A "what am I" haiku: C. Nelson Reilly / Greater than or equal to / Strike anywhere, yes?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry, haiku

> C. Nelson Reilly
>
> Greater than or equal to
>
> Strike anywhere, yes?

One word in many of its senses will fit this haiku

Given the answer below, an explanation that is more than a hint

> In Microsoft Excel, the MATCH() function has a parameter for "match type"; -1 is the parameter value to indicate a match type of "greater than or equal to"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Match 
>  Charles Nelson Reilly was a regular panelist on the Match Game 
>  Compare is a synonym of match - tfitzger 
>  Strike Anywhere is a type of fire-making match.

Comment: They could be asking for `match` as a synonym to `compare`, like "can you match these socks?"